# How start remote debug on the very first run in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

How start remote debug on the very first app run in react native?

I use developer menu to start `Open debugger` and the app reloads so it's not possible to debug code that occurs on a very first run only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found a solution in this [article](https://www.bram.us/2017/12/23/launch-a-react-native-app-with-debug-js-remotely-enabled-by-default/).

It's possible to start `Open Debugger` programmatically on `iOS`

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

if (__DEV__) {
 NativeModules.DevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely(true)
}
```

[react-native-devsettings-android](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-devsettings-android) library is required to run this code on `android`

Comment: This is interesting to find out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to hardcode it in native code.

For android i believe its this one:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/786c1ecc2a6856967d676da68eb02f89eb38fb79/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/devsupport/DevInternalSettings.java#L88